# All you politicians are the same

Tags: grammar, usage

Are these five sentences correct and interchangeable?

> 1) "You politicians are all the same."
>
> 2) "All of you politicians are the same."
>
> 3) "All you politicians are the same."
>
> 4) "You politicians all are the same."
>
> 5) "You all politicians are the same."

I think 4 and 5 are wrong but 1 and 2 are right. Somehow 3 sounds like wrong to me.
As far as I can remember, we can say like **"All your friends are the same"** instead of **"All of your friends are the same"**, but I am not sure if I can say **"All you politicians are the same"** instead of **"All of you politicians are the same"**.

Answer (score 1):

Of your example sentences, the 5th one is awkward

> 5) You all politicians are the same.

It borders on the southern / midwest accent of

> ya'll are the same

The rest are fine and interchangeable.

Comment: @FireandIce Actually, the fourth sentence is at least verging on the ungrammatical.

Comment: I definitely find the fourth one weird, though I have noticed that Americans will often put an adverb before a verb in cases where I would never do so.